# Set `--net-alias` using Docker API?

Tags: networking, docker

I have the following flow using following docker APIs:

- build image
- create container
- connect container to network (using existing network id)
- start container

I would like to somehow set the alternative network name for the container, i.e. so called network alias that in CLI can be set using the `--net-alias`.

How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was in the docs, although not so explicitly: by providing the body with `EndpointConfig` you may set the alias:

```
{
    "Container": containerId,
    "EndpointConfig": {
        "Aliases": ["alias1"]

}
```